# heatmap.js is not rendering in my website

Tags: javascript, html, heatmap

I am trying heat map for my app, but I think there is something missing in my code because it's not working.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7jzsjrvo/)

Below is my code:

```
<div  class="example-1" style="position: relative;">
    <canvas id="heatmapf" width="320" height="270" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></canvas>
</div>

<script>
    var domElement = document.getElementById( "heatmapf" );
    var heatmap = h337.create({
        container: domElement
    });

    heatmap.setData({
        max: 5,
        data: [{ x: 10, y: 15, value: 5}, { x: 20, y: 25, value: 8}]
    });
</script>
```

I am new to this heat map and want a very basic example in my app. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please attach the relevant code here, a fiddle is always good to have but what if the link expires? Kinda useless question then.

Comment: I have updated the question though i have just created js fiddle ad it wll not expire so quick. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creator of heatmap.js here. It seems that you are trying to use the `<canvas>` element as a heatmap container.

That won't work because heatmap.js automatically appends its own `<canvas>` to the `container` element thus you'd need a container element such as `<div>, <p>` so you should rather pass

`document.querySelector( ".example-1" );`

as the container element. If it still doesn't work you most likely have not set a container size (the container element should either have a width, height set, or `width` and `height` should be passed in the heatmap configuration.

You can also find more basic heatmap examples [on the heatmap.js website](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/examples.html)

Comment: This is my JS fiddle. Can you edit anything in this? https://jsfiddle.net/7jzsjrvo/

Comment: I even downloaded GITHUB fiels from the website but heatmap.js-master\examples are also not working.